# To show the function holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in H(\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R})$ and $f$ continuous in $\mathbb{C}$. Then to show that $f ∈ H(\mathbb{C})$.

I thought I should apply Morera's theorem. SO I need to show that for all rectangles in $\mathbb{C}$ the line integral over the boundary of $f$ is zero. But how should i use $f \in H(\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R})$ here ? 
I am stuck

Comment: Triangles are much more convenient than rectangles. Anyway, if the figure lies entirely in one open half-plane, Cauchy's integral theorem gives you the vanishing of the integral. If the figure touches the real line, use the continuity to deduce the vanishing. If the figure crosses the real line, split it.